# What is the correct way to free an interface behind an OleVariant?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007, finalization

I am trying to find a safe/deterministic way to release an interface which is encapsulated in an OleVariant.

AFAICS Delphi releases interface references at the end of a procedure, but in my case I have to do it earlier, because I have to shut down COM.

```
procedure Test;
var
  LLibrary: OleVariant;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    LLibrary := Null;
    try
      LLibrary := CreateOleObject(LibraryName);
    finally
      LLibrary := Unassigned; // <-- I would like to release the interface here
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize; // <-- Shutdown of COM
  end;
end; // <-- The compiler releases the interface here
```

I though of putting the OleVariant in an extra class instance that I can free before I call `CoUninitialize`.

```
procedure Test;
var
  Container: TLibraryContainer; // Holds the OleVariant
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    Container := TLibraryContainer.Create;
    try
      {...}
    finally
      Container.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Is this solution safe or is there a better solution I have overlooked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is clearly using an implicit local interface variable for the return value from `CreateOleObject`. This is then released at the end of the routine, too late for you.

There are a couple of ways to defeat this. First of all you could be explicit about the `IDispatch` interface reference returned by `CreateOleObject`. This allows you to control its lifetime.

```
procedure Test;
var
  intf: IDispatch;
  LLibrary: OleVariant;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    intf := CreateOleObject(LibraryName);
    try
      LLibrary := intf;
    finally
      VarClear(LLibrary);
      intf := nil;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

An alternative would be to move the code that called `CreateOleObject` into a separate routine with its own scope.

```
procedure DoWork;
var
  LLibrary: OleVariant;
begin
  LLibrary := CreateOleObject(LibraryName);
  //do stuff with LLibrary
end;

procedure Test;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    DoWork;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Since the implicit local reference is within the scope of `DoWork` it is released at the end of `DoWork` and therefore before you run `CoUninitialize`.

My recommendation is to use the second option which is cleaner and forces the compiler to do the work on your behalf.

Comment: The only real option is using the secondary routine, unless you enjoy counting function calls and inspecting generated assembler code to make sure there are no hidden local variables. +1 for calling your `DoWork` routine... `DoWork`, see my deleted answer for details.

Comment: @Cosmin I agree that the second option is better.

Comment: Actually my real code is a bit more sophisticated and I think that I will have to use your first variant, but I will try to refactor the code so that I can use the second one. :)